# How to plot a factorial function in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot:

[image]

Using the following R code with no success:

```
N= seq(from=150, to=2000)
P=((factorial(60) / factorial(50))*(factorial(N-60) /factorial(N-150))) /(factorial(N) /factorial(N-100))
plot(N,P)
```

Comment: Please do not cross-post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224996/40036

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost always, probability expression involving factorial is some result of "N choose K" computation:

[image]

But it is very inefficient to compute this via factorial, and most importantly, it is not numerically stable. Have a look at your code using `factorial()`: you got `NaN`.

In R, the `choose(N, K)` function computes "N choose K" fast and stably.

Now, a careful inspection of your given formulation shows that it is equivalent to:

```
choose(N-100, 50) / choose(N, 60)
```

So, you can do:

```
P <- choose(N-100, 50) / choose(N, 60)
plot(N, P, type = "l")
```

[image]

---

**Follow-up**

> Hi, this is a very efficient function. But mean, mode, and median of this plot doesn't match the ones I have in my course materials for the same plot? The mean should be 727, Mode= 600, median= 679!! How can I get these descriptives from your suggested plot?

I am confused by what your course material is trying to do. The probability you give is conditional probability `P(D | N)`, i.e., a probability for random variable `D`. While we sketch `P` against `N`. **Hence, the plot above is not a probability mass function!** Then, how can we use it to compute statistics like mean, mode and median, for random variable `N`???

Well anyway, since you ask and insist on getting an answer, let's **pretend** this is a probability mass function for random variable `N`. But since it is not a true one, `sum(P)` is not or even close to 1. We actually have `sum(P) = 3.843678e-12`. So, to use it as a proper probability mass function, we need to normalize it first.

```
P <- P / sum(P)
```

Now `P` sum up to 1.

To compute mean, we do

```
sum(N * P)
# [1] 726.978
```

To compute mode, we do

```
N[which.max(P)]
# 599
```

To compute median, we do

```
N[which(cumsum(P) > 0.5)[1]]
# 679
```

Comment: Hi, this is a very efficient function But mean, mode, and median of this plot doesn't match the ones I have in my course materials for the same plot? The mean should be 727, Mode= 600, median= 679!! How can I get these descriptives from your suggested plot?

Comment: Zheyuan, I'm new to this forum, and I highly appreciate your answer, how should I accept your previous answer?

Comment: You got it! So, mean, mode, and median of this plot doesn't match the ones I have in my course materials for the same plot? The mean should be 727, Mode= 600, median= 679!! How can I get these descriptives from your suggested plot?

Comment: Zheyuan, How about SD of the distribution? Also, you noted that a "a careful inspection of [my] given formulation shows that it is equivalent to: "choose(N-100, 50) / choose(N, 60)". Does finding this equivalency require sold math background or it is relatively easy?