# Probability choose (N, K) R

Tags: r, probability

I have calculated a likelihood function for a sampling without replacement problem.

[image]

How can, theoretically, we can convert this likelihood function into a `choose(N, K)` form?

Additionally, if I plot this function such that N is my X axis and probability given by this function is the Y axis, what is the variance of the plotted distribution?

Thanks,

Comment: I mean how you Arrived at choose(N-100, 50) / choose(N, 60)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a follow-up to [How to plot a factorial function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38510834/4891738). I will **not** repeat information / background / code given in my answer there.

Regarding your requestion for derivation, it is simply:

[image]

Don't ask any more; do a little math yourself. This is a programming site, not for a question like this.

Now, regarding computation of variance, we use statistical result: `var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X) ^ 2`.

```
## P has been scaled in below

## mean
MEAN <- sum(N * P)
# [1] 726.978

## variance
VAR <- sum(N * (N * P)) - MEAN ^ 2
# [1] 55342.9

## standard deviation
SD <- sqrt(VAR)
# [1] 235.2507
```